# Android initiate application shutdown from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Whats the best way to initiate application shutdown from an Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [How to close Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application). The answer there has everything you need to know and more!

Comment: Interesting.  However if one wants to use the finish approach, how could one reach each activity in the app and call finish on each.  I could call finish on current activity, but what about the other activities?