# How to close an android application

Tags: android

I need to close an application through a button click. How to do this?

Comment: Please watch this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  setContentView(R.layout.button);
  Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCloseAbout); 
  Button1.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  finish();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, android model doesn't consider manual exiting the applications. They are keep in memory as long as resources allow system to do that. But if want force the application to exit you can call finish() on your current activity, but you won't see any difference for your application with clicking back or home button.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very late response, but this is a perfect solution.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(i); 
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Android will take you to the menu and you close the application.
easy.

Answer (score 1):

this work for me

1. create static `Boolean` variable, for example `(sysExit)` on 1st `activity = false`
2. override `onResume()` in every activity
3. inside onResume add `if(sysExit) finish();`
4. on exit button access the Boolean and make it true then finish this activity

this will close all in the stack till application exit ;)

```
protected void onResume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (app_exit)
        {           
            finish();           
            Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method `finish()`, this will finish the current activity.
Note that this is exactly the same thing as pressing the back button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call finish() method on onClick() method of the of Button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `activity.finish()`

Answer (score 0):

To close Android Application what i do was adding android:launchMode="singleTask" to my main activity in the maniphest...and then this code when i want to close the app

```
System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
System.exit(0);
```