# How to force stop the application

Tags: android

Is there any possibilities to force stop the android application through program. previously i used finish(); method, but by doing this i can only quit the current activity and place back into existing or previous activity. i want to kill or force close the application, is this possible to do in android application. pls guide me to do this..Thanks in advance.

Comment: system.exit(0); i guess... :)

Comment: No this one also doing the same functionally what finish() has been doing. do have any alternative idea..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can be helpful in getting your answer
[How to close Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application)

I got some code..may be this is helpful to you

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(startMain);
```

call this on your button's click event,It'll exit the application
and yes..before you exit.just call System.gc()..I know it's just a warning.but it may be helpful in releasing some memory

Answer (score 1):

Using System.exit(0); is not recommanded but works.

In fact it's better to do something like :
    System.gc();
    finish();

This will ask the system garbage to start cleaning clean, then finishing properly the apps.