# How to force close an app

Tags: android, process

When my app crashes, it loads again in a random activity instead of being force closed.

When I call `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` it follows that behaviour too.

I just want my app to force close if needed and let the user send me their reports.

What should I do to avoid that behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it loads some random activity? Usually it loads the next activity on top of your app's activity stack.

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7240460/262462:

1. start first activity (either splash screen, or whatever activity is currently at the bottom of the activity stack) with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP (which will quit all the other activities started after it, which means - all of them). Just make to have this activity in the activity stack (not finish it for some reason in advance).
2. call finish() on this activity