# How to kill a progress in Android

Tags: android, kill, progress

when I tried to exit, I run the code below, but I can't kill the progress,

so if I restart my App, another progress started.what's the matter?

my exit code:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
    System.exit(0);
    finish();
```

Comment: for uploding the image you need to increase your reputation score which is 1 right now... you need to be registered member in the site with at least 10 reputation in order to gain the privilege to use this feature http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: is this activity is your root activity or only activity in stack currenly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application

Comment: btw, you can upload images using http://imgur.com/ and share the link here, till you are allowed to upload images in SO

Comment: yes,it's my root activity,I can finish it but when I restart it, I can see another progress in DDMS,the original still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code to end your application

```
 finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Why call finish() first? Will that not close the activity before it can start another one?

Comment: yes it will close activity and then start a new activity with flag of clear top by which the activity stack will get cleared and the second flag ensure the home screen so all the process will quietly get stopped and application get closed