# Kill another application on Android?

Tags: android

I am try to kill my another application. But this code is not able to kill my another application. I know to kill another application is a bad idea. But I have a learning purpose, and I have tried to kill. My code part:

```
Button runningApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.runningApp);
runningApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String nameOfProcess = "com.example.filepath";
        ActivityManager  manager = (ActivityManager)ApplicationActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> listOfProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : listOfProcesses)
        {
            if (process.processName.contains(nameOfProcess))
            {
                Log.e("Proccess" , process.processName + " : " + process.pid);
                android.os.Process.killProcess(process.pid);
                android.os.Process.sendSignal(process.pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
                manager.killBackgroundProcesses(process.processName);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have added Permissions, and they are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Every time I can see the [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file), the particular application is running in the background. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: This kind of thing is a serious security concern so is regulated heavily. If you do not own the application you're trying to kill I don't think it's possible but if you do I think it can be done. Why don't you give a little more detail about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Recently I am referred Google Play, Here Some one is launched applications are Task Killer. Is it possible? If it is possible, Please any one explain how it is possible. I need to learn in the concepts.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40266343/5235263

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can only kill a process that has the same userID as the one that is doing the killing. If you are trying to kill your own process it should work. Otherwise you can't do it (unless you have a rooted device and your application has root priviledges).

Comment: Recently I am referred `Google Play`, Here Some one is launched applications are Task Killer. Is it possible?

Comment: Task Killer just kills background tasks. It can't kill other running apps. And it isn't necessary. Android will kill off stuff that isn't needed on its own.

Comment: David I agree Your answer. I need one help. How to Kill Background Tasks through programmatically. I need to learn, so you can trained me. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814696/how-to-kill-currently-running-task-in-android

Comment: I have read a lot of topics about trying to "STOP" another 3rd party application within you own application. Its look like something impossible (unless you are rooted). In the other hand, all android versions let users stop any services or application manually: Settings>App>running app> STOP. So HOW COME THERE IS NO WHAY TO DO IT PROGRAMMATICALLY? Is Android a really open source program?

Answer (score 3):

If your device is rooted and your app is located in /system/app then you can kill another app by disabling and enabling it via:

```
pm.setApplicationEnabledSetting(packageName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);
pm.setApplicationEnabledSetting(packageName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 0);
```

This will kill the app and make it accessible once again. Note that homescreen shortcuts disappear though.

Comment: Certain apps do not respond to the `killBackgroundProcesses(...)` method, like Pandora for instance. The above method does seem to work on just about every case I tested though. +1!