# Check if app is running and kill

Tags: android

I was wondering if I can kill app from other app. I mean I want to create application which when I start this application I will check status other application and if app, which name is for example "Startex" is running then I kill "Startex" app and run my second application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not. Only `Android` can kill application if it needs memory. In order to do this you should know the `PID` of the application you want to kill and invoke a syscall at kernel level

Answer (score 0):

If both apps are designed by you then you can have shared [user id](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) in both the Apps then you can kill another app [here is the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036895/kill-another-application-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

This can't be, or at least should never be done. Android itself is supposed to control when an app is no longer required, usually based on needing to free up some memory for another app that may be opened. Google frown upon developers killing the app themselves without letting Android handle it, and likely would never receive any promo place on the play store from Google.