# I want to kill/ close a particular app by pressing a button in my current app. How can I do this?

Tags: java, android

Here's what i want:
My app is having a button for closing another independent application say - Google map. I want to know if the process has started and if it does then i want to close it by pressing that button.

Comment: What did you find online? What hace you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036895/kill-another-application-in-android

Comment: The application that i want to close/kill doesn't have the same user id i,e it's not my application... @Knells

Answer (score 4):

You can use the BroadcastReceiver Class.
Try this way.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (isAppForground(context)) {
            // App is in Foreground
        } else {
            // App is in Background
        }
    }

    public boolean isAppForground(Context mContext) {

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
            ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
            if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(mContext.getPackageName())) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```