# Android force stop apps

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, forceclose

I have nexus 6p and running android N developer preview. I have 3 GB of RAM and most of the RAM is in used like 2.2 GB. Is there any way to force stop other Apps programatically ? Let's say there is a package called "com.whatsapp". Can I force stop by package name ? I have googled  this and gone through couple of threads but I couldn't find for my device. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only kill a process that has the same userID as the one that is doing the killing. If you are trying to kill your own process it should work. Otherwise you can't do it (unless you have a rooted device and your application has root priviledges).

See [Kill another application on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036895/kill-another-application-on-android)

Comment: Thanks mate! This is what I was looking for.