# Kill Android app from another application on Marshmallow

Tags: android, kill-process

I wanted to Kill android app from another application on Marshmallow but the below code not working

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kill another application on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036895/kill-another-application-on-android)

Comment: but its not working in marshmallow any more