# Kill an app by using its package name

Tags: android

how can I completely destroy any third party running app by using its particular package name?

I have tried this code but it doesn't kill the app

`ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);`
 `mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcess(your package name);`

Comment: First, your app has to have the appropriate privileges to do that.

Comment: What type of privileges ? How can I do that

Comment: Already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036895/kill-another-application-on-android

Comment: @asc42 hii, I tried that code but failed to kill the running app