# How to close total application in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android application development.

I developed one android application, in this application when the user presses back or exit buttons I call the finish() method. This method closes the current activity only.

My requirement is when i click on the exit button, it should close all activities and it show the menu page.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This subject has received some discussion, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application?rq=1) is one that should contain most of the information you're looking for.

Also, see Activity Lifecycle and Process Lifecycle in the [Android Documentation on Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to understand the hows and whys of closing apps.

Answer (score 3):

When you go from **A** activity to **B** activity, call `finish()`.so in `android stack` **A** activity ll get `finish() or get killed`. when you press back or exit button on top activity then stacks gets empty, then you ll go to menu screen or home screen.

for example : when your going from **A activity to B activity** perform below step:

```
startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class));
finish();
```

so your **A** activity gets finish, & your new **B** activity gets started. Here when you press back button or exit button you ll go to home screen or menu screen.

Here we have **two methods** to `finish or kill` the app on **back button pressed**.

1. Using `finish()` which **closes or finishes** the current activity on android screen.

   for example : you have 2 activities i.e **A** & **B**. You ll go from **A** activity to **B** activity using intent, now foreground acitivity is **B**, you want to go back & kill **B** activity & goto **A** acitivity use `finish()` onclick of backbutton. If your on **A** activity then it closes the app. see below code.

   ```
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
   finish();
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
   ```
2. Using `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` which kills the app i.e force close the app & goto the home screen.see below code.

   ```
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
   // Kills & force closes the app 
   android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
   ```

Comment: @CommonsWare -- your right, should not use killProcess(). Its not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

> My requirement is when i click on the exit button, it should close all activities and it show the menu page.

Assuming "the menu page" is an activity of yours, call `startActivity()`, with an `Intent` identifying your "menu page", and include `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as flags on your `Intent`. That will clear all activities from your task and bring your existing "menu page" to the foreground (or create an instance of the "menu page" if there is none).