# How can I prevent users from being able to "force stop" my application on Android?

Tags: android

Is there any possible way to be secure from this kind of activity?
Or is there any way to get the notification for this 'Force stop' activity.
Because I don't want that users can easily stop my app.

Comment: Your app is getting forced stop because of exceptions in your program. Best and ideal way to deal with this is to fix those bugs/exceptions.

Comment: You want the user to not be able to stop your app?.. sounds fishy

Comment: @ krishnabhdara,I am not talking about'getting forced stop'.I am talking about 'forcestop' button which is in the settings of android phone so i want that is there any api by which i can make my app secure.

Comment: Why do you think interrupting user requests to stop it will _make your app secure_?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to disable the `Force Stop` button for third party apps for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [What “Force stop” button means?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33801/what-force-stop-button-means) first.

If there is an instance of an application is in stack or any service running behind, then "Force Close" button is in active mode.

To prevent from this, you should either "fully close" your application or need to check "no service will be in background" after exit.

To kill application refer following links

- [How to close Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application)