# How does the 'close all' button on touchwiz's multitasking window work?

Tags: android

I was wondering if it was possible to close an app in android.

I came across the 'close all' button on samsung's touchwiz ui in the multitasking interface.

Can anyone tell me how this works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application)

Comment: This is just a guess, but most multitasking interfaces on Android is generally just shortcuts to the most recent apps, and not running apps. So by clicking the "close all" button, I'd think that it just removes those "shortcuts" while nothing really happens to the app's lifecycle it self. But again, I'm not certain on this.