# Closing an android application programatically in android

Tags: android

I have a application that has two activities

- Activity1
- Activity2

Now i start `Activity1` and move to `Activity2` now i want to close the application at a moment

- If i use `finish()` i am able to close only `Activity2` and not
  `Activity1`

---

**What i want to do** ::

1. i want my application to quit(close all activities and go to
   homescreen)
2. But i don't want my apk to be removed from android system itself
3. How can i achieve this ?

### {Edit}

- I used the code(Activity2 has a fragment which launched a dialog on
  "ok" condition in positive condition  i am performing this condition below)
- I am able to launch the previous activity but it is not canceled, its
  just reloaded

---

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SplashActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent); 
                getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your `Activity2` as "top task" with a `Flag` when you call it as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

See the [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK):

> If set in an Intent passed to *Context.startActivity()*, this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started. That is, **the activity becomes the new root** of an otherwise empty task, and any old activities are finished.

Then, call `finish()` in your `Activity2`. This should do the trick.

Comment: [+1] for your input ... please look at the edit ... i have some deadlock in solving this issue

Comment: I don't clearly understand @Sky when you said: "*the **previous** activity but it is not **canceled**, its just reloaded*". Can you explain a little more this please?

Comment: I am able to launch the Activity1(which is a splash screen) ..... but i dont know where to place the finish() code .... still the activity is not closing(splash(Activity1) is the first activity)..... i added bundle and tried as shown in this question ....please check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455326/finish-not-working-in-closing-the-activity i think i need to add more conditions i guess

Comment: As I can understand on your other question @Sky, you should call `finish` after `startActivity` in *startingNewActivity* method. `finish` is normally calling when another activity is launched.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to kill your application process, but it is not recommended

`this.finish();
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());`

This will kill your application and releases all the memory associated with it.

**Note:** Assuming your app has a single process id

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);  
Activity1.this.finish();
```

Comment: if you use this finish current activity only,if one more activity its not working

Comment: Sure @Boopathi, but if you use `finish` for each activity, this resolve the issue.

Comment: @boopathi,ya you wont get that previous activity by pressing back key

Comment: @Sania if use 3 or more activity its doesn't work.1.i want my application to quit(close all activities and go to homescreen)

Comment: @Fllo everyone keep the all activities alive until logout.If you use every activity finish(),its doesn't give good application

Comment: can u post your exact class(only finish part) where it is not working.because the logic is same for all activities,i think u r doing something wrong,as i have used it for 30 classes,it has no issue,

Comment: Not necessary, @Boopathi, all depends on the app you built! However, I didn't use this feature (finish each activity when you lanch another) for the reason that you mentioned (kill activities with logout).

Comment: @Boopathi : **"everyone keep the all activities alive"** This is not true. There are very many cases where I finish an `Activity` after starting a new one. It depends entirely on the design of the app and what each `Activity` does.

Comment: If you  use 30 activity ,your code doesn't kill the all activity,they asked the question is when i go to home screen ,my previous activity have been killed.

Comment: it is finishing your current Activity by finish(),so u are able to go to homescreen.Where you are getting problem.i think sky problem got solved by this method

Comment: @Squonk for example you have 30 button in activity,30 buttons redirect to some other activity ,at that time you have  given a finish() in all onclicklistner of buttons.Its doesn't give a code efficiency.

Comment: after every intent i do like this,in case of 30 button,i can handle it by writing once(i ll prefer use switch case)

Comment: @Boopathi : If you have 30 buttons in an `Activity` then you should have the `Activity` implement `View.OnClickListener` with a single `onClick(...)` method instead of using 30 anonymous `OnClickListener` instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intObj=new Intent(this, Homescree.class);
intObj.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intObj);
```