# how to close application once a CountDownTimer is finished?

Tags: android

My application contains a **CountDownTimer** (15 minutes) and a **list of applications** (Browser, calculator, Music, ..).
what I want is when I run an application from this list, the selected application starts normally and closes once the counter is finished.

I use this code to start selected application:

```
Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot kill an application, its in the hands of Android OS. But you can finish the current activity by calling `finish()`.

Comment: Not sure that answered to the question. The OP wants to finish an "external" app from his own application. And you can [kill an app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2092951/2668136) (with `killProcess`) but as you said, it's really not recommended!