# Can't end my android application

Tags: java, android

I'm currently getting into android development.
I try to let the user end the application by a menu button.
This is my attempt:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_exit) {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The application window closes, but when I switch to the "open applications window" it is still there. How can I end/kill/close/shutdown my application completely?

Comment: Using `finish()` instead of `super.onDestroy()` ends your activity. The window you call `open applications` is the `recents` window: the last used applications that may or may not be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about closing your app twice, since it is not the way Android apps usually work. Instead of this you should use the code as follow:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_exit) {
        finish()
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

If you really want to exit your application manually, please check out the accepted answer from the following post: [How to close Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application)