# SQLite inserts three rows instead of one

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to insert one row with `id` and `timestamp` into a sqlite database by clicking in my android app on virtual device.

```
private final String create_table = "CREATE TABLE clicks ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, timestamp INTEGER(4) NOT NULL);";

db.execSQL("insert into clicks(timestamp) values (strftime(\"%s\", CURRENT_TIME));");
```

When I run the app inserts three rows into the db instead of one row?

Any suggestion?

Here the MainActivity :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SQLite sqlite = new SQLite( this );
    sqlite.open();

    sqlite.insert();

    sqlite.close();

    System.exit(0);

}

}
```

When I close it, the app restarts twice. "System.exit(0)"

```
02-21 18:10:11.558 2232-2232/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
02-21 18:10:11.558 2232-2232/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
02-21 18:10:11.575 1203-1216/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.click.nautilus.click (pid 2232) has died
02-21 18:10:11.581 2246-2246/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-21 18:10:11.595 1203-1216/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 2246:com.click.nautilus.click/u0a54 for activity com.click.nautilus.click/.MainActivity
```

Comment: You can use the ContentValues for inserting into database. Debug with breakpoint how it is inserting the 3 times

Comment: Post your `onClickListener`.

Comment: you are probably calling 3 times, show the whole class

Comment: No onClickListener implemented.

Comment: How do you know three rows are inserted into the database? How did you confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue.
`System.exit(0)` is not recommended to finish an app.

Thank you again.

Finally the `MainActivity` looks like that:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SQLite sqlite = new SQLite(this);
    sqlite.open();

    sqlite.insert();

    sqlite.close();

    setResult(0);
    finish();

}
```

More info about closing app:

[How to close Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application)