# How to close a activity and exit the app in background when a button is clicked in Android in this scenario below?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am developing a Chat App, the app is in closed state. The Caller A makes a Call to another user B. The User's B app open, IncomingCallActivity.java there is reject call button, when reject button is clicked the call get disconnected but the app is not closed. The IncomingCallActivity always remains in minimised state. How to handle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application)

Comment: Call `finish()` to close an activity.

Comment: @SrikarReddy finish() will just close the activity , i need to clear the app from background

Comment: Are you trying to close app after termination of call? Is this your expectation?

Comment: @MohanRajS Yes i am trying to close the application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should set `excludeFromRecents` to `true` for your `IncomingCallActivity` in Manifest file :

```
<activity
    android:name=".IncomingCallActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

or you can set flag to intent that opens `IncomingCallActivity` :

```
Intent incomingCallActivityIntent=new Intent(this,IncomingCallActivity.calss);
incomingCallActivityIntent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
startActivity(incomingCallActivityIntent);
```

and after call finished call `finish()` method