# How to exit from the application and show the home screen?

Tags: android, exit, back-button

I have an application where on the home page I have buttons for navigation through the application.

On that page I have a button "EXIT" which when clicked should take the user to the home screen on the phone where the application icon is.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 331, accepted):

Android's design does not favor exiting an application by choice, but rather manages it by the OS. You can bring up the Home application by its corresponding Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You can even use..  "moveTaskToBack(true);"

Comment: will it dealocate all the resources? Because when I exit the app this way and after some time I click the app icon again. It starts from where I left it. That means the app was still running in the background.

Comment: Thanks it worked very fine +1 for that. Also why does the system.exit(0) does not work?

Comment: This can not be removed from recent apps list

Comment: This keeps your app in the background, so it does not exit the application.

Comment: This answer will just make the home screen appear and will not exit/close the application completely as the OP wants.

Comment: This will be helpful for you:  moveTaskToBack(true);
                      android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                      System.exit(1);

Comment: This is problematic with fragments for me.

Comment: @hB0 that would work only if you have one activity in your application. It just closes the current activity.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me and close the app in second activity.

Comment: have problems  in more test

Answer (score 73):

May be you can try something like this

Suppose in our application, we have a number of activities(say ten) and we need to exit directly from this activity. What we can do is, create an intent and go to the root activity and set flag in the intent as

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

also, add some extra like boolean to the intent

```
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
```

Then in root activity, check the value of the `boolean` and according to that call finish(), in the `onCreate()` of the root activity

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
 finish();
}
```

Comment: Just do nothing in onCreate to invoke finish.

Comment: In my case I had to override `onNewIntent` as well. Because the intnet.getExtras() kept being null.

Comment: And this method will restart your `RootActivity` instead of resuming it from stack. Check here to overcome this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26258455/609782

Answer (score 31):

```
System.exit(0);
```

Is probably what you are looking for. It will close the entire application and take you to the home Screen.

Comment: Should that be a lowercase exit?

Comment: should be System.exit(0). But it's not very useful anyway.

Comment: it gives exception on Tab running on OS 3.0, and the exception can't be cached.

Comment: System.exit(0) should not be used as advised by the core Android team.

Comment: I think this is the best approach for exceptional circumstances. Say for an app that needs internet and the connection breaks a few activities into the app. An alert dialog can be displayed (without buttons). The Back button needs to exit the entire app since reentry requires login/initialization again. System.exit is the only thing that works reasonably I've found. Not sure about @user1699548 comment though.

Comment: Will this kill all services related to that app as well?

Comment: @DineshVenkata what should be used then?

Comment: @shoosh youraActivity.finish()

Comment: Using System.exit(0) will bypass the onDestroy method of an Activity

Answer (score 25):

This works well for me.
Close all the previous activities as follows:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Then in MainActivity onCreate() method add this to finish the MainActivity

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
        finish();
        return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for me.  It leaves my app with nothing visible, but still running some how.  I can see threads hanging around and waiting in the debugger that will never actually do anything.

Answer (score 23):

first finish your application using method `finish();`

and then add below lines in onDestroy for Removing Force close

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
super.onDestroy();
```

Comment: never use this, because it gets no chance to free resources

Comment: -1 because onDestroy is executed whenever you leave the activity, not only when back key is pressed.

Comment: @Jacky: and how does killing the process not free any system resources?

Comment: Why is the `super.onDestroy()` after the `killProcess()` ? would this line even be reached?

Comment: doesn't this also kill all your services as well?

Answer (score 20):

If you want to end an activity you can simply call `finish()`.
It is however bad practice to have an exit button on the screen.

Comment: I'm using it for "You need to update this app to the latest version", and I don't want them to continue using it. Still bad practice...?

Comment: @beetree Yes. Like any bad practice, there are cases where it's your only option, and you use it because trying to do something else would be nonsensical. The point of it being _bad practice_, as opposed to _illegal syntax_, is that it's available for those few cases, but you should try your darndest to find a better way to do it. In your case, there isn't one.

Answer (score 17):

Some Activities actually you don't want to open again when back button pressed such Splash Screen Activity, Welcome Screen Activity, Confirmation Windows. Actually you don't need this in activity stack. you can do this using=> open manifest.xml file and add a attribute

> android:noHistory="true"

to these activities.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.shoppingapp.AddNewItems"
    android:label="" 
    android:noHistory="true">
</activity>
```

OR

Sometimes you want close the entire application in certain back button press. Here best practice is open up the home window instead of exiting application. For that you need to override onBackPressed() method. usually this method open up the top activity in the stack.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(a);

}
```

OR

In back button pressed you want to exit that activity and also you also don't want to add this in activity stack. call finish() method inside onBackPressed() method. it will not make  close the entire application. it will go for the previous activity in the stack.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  finish();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

It is not recommended to exit your Android Application. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238) for more details.

The user can always quit your app through the home button or in the first activity through the back button.

Comment: @janusz: pressing home button never quit android application, instead it goes in background...

Answer (score 5):

(I tried previous answers but they lacks in some points. For example if you don't do a `return;` after finishing activity, remaining activity code runs. Also you need to edit onCreate with return. If you doesn't run super.onCreate() you will get a runtime error)

Say you have `MainActivity` and `ChildActivity`.

Inside ChildActivity add this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ChildActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
return true;
```

Inside MainActivity's onCreate add this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    // your current codes
    // your current codes
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another option, to use the FinishAffinity method to close all the tasks in the stack related to the app.

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27765687/1984636

Answer (score 3):

When u call finish onDestroy() of that activity will be called and it will go back to previous activity in the activity stack... So.. for exit do not call finish();

Answer (score 3):

Here's what i did:

**SomeActivity.java**

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(this,QuitAppActivity.class);
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(newIntent);
            finish();
    }
```

**QuitAppActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      finish();
}
```

Basically what you did is cleared all activities from the stack and launch `QuitAppActivity`, that will finish the task.

Comment: Good approach. No need to pass values via Intent.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `moveTaskToBack(true)` in your exit button's `onClickedListener` to minimize the application.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines after `finish();` in `onDestroy()`:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
super.onDestroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried exiting application using following code snippet, this it worked for me. Hope this helps you. 
i did small demo with 2 activities

first activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private Button secondActivityBtn;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        secondActivityBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.SecondActivityBtn);
        secondActivityBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        pref = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editer = pref.edit();

        if(pref.getInt("exitApp", 0) == 1){
            editer.putInt("exitApp", 0);
            editer.commit();
            finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.SecondActivityBtn:
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourAnyActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

your any other activity

```
public class YourAnyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button exitAppBtn;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_any);

        exitAppBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitAppBtn);
        exitAppBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        pref = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editer = pref.edit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.exitAppBtn:
            Intent main_intent = new Intent(YourAnyActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            main_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(main_intent);
            editer.putInt("exitApp",1);
            editer.commit();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with observer mode.

Observer interface

```
public interface Observer {
public void update(Subject subject);
}
```

Base Subject

```
public class Subject {
private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();

public void attach(Observer observer){
    observers.add(observer);
}

public void detach(Observer observer){
    observers.remove(observer);
}

protected void notifyObservers(){
    for(Observer observer : observers){
        observer.update(this);
    }
}
}
```

Child Subject implements the exit method

```
public class ApplicationSubject extends Subject {
public void exit(){
    notifyObservers();
}
}
```

MyApplication which your application should extends it

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static ApplicationSubject applicationSubject;

public ApplicationSubject getApplicationSubject() {
            if(applicationSubject == null) applicationSubject = new ApplicationSubject();
    return applicationSubject;
}
```

}

Base Activity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity implements Observer {

public MyApplication app;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    app = (MyApplication) this.getApplication();
    app.getApplicationSubject().attach(this);
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            app.getApplicationSubject().detach(this);
    super.finish();
}

/**
 * exit the app
 */
public void close() {
    app.getApplicationSubject().exit();
};

@Override
public void update(Subject subject) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.finish();
}

}
```

let's test it

```
public class ATestActivity extends BaseActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    close(); //invoke 'close'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exit application 
put this code under your function

```
public void yourFunction()
{
finishAffinity();   
moveTaskToBack(true);

}



//For an instance, if you want to exit an application on double click of a 
//button,then the following code can be used.
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 2) {
        // do something on back.
        From Android 16+ you can use the following:

        finishAffinity();
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100% works fine. this is code for Exit your app onClick (Method)

```
    Button exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exitbutton);

    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

            finish();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Closed Completely and Safely", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my code can hepls (Main_Activity.java):

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.finish();
        exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        switch(keyCode)    {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("My application").setMessage("Keep playing?").setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                // Go to backgroung
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { moveTaskToBack(true); }
                });
                // Exit from app calling protected void onDestroy()
                builder.setNegativeButton("CLOSE APPLICATION", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { onDestroy(); }
                });
                // Close this dialog
                builder.setNeutralButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { dialog.cancel(); }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest one

```
finish();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

This will close the app and without destroying the methods services this task will be completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `finish();` `moveTaskToBack(true);` and `System.exit(1);` to quit your application.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit Application?");
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            finish();
                            moveTaskToBack(true);
                            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                            System.exit(1);
                        }
                    })

            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to exit from your application. Then use this code inside your button pressed event.
**like:**

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    System.exit(1);
}
```