# Android application force closed while exiting the application

Tags: android

Another problem in my android application. When i click on home button, it exits from the application but saying `Sorry, the application has stopped unexpectedly`

The code for my home button is

```
ImageView home  =   (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.home1);
    home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            kalma1.stop();
            Intent i =new Intent(Kalma1.this, null);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

and the console says the following

```
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1110 objects / 70984 bytes in 77ms
Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:76)
at android.content.Intent.<init>  (Intent.java:2678)
at com.kalmas.Kalma1$5.onClick(Kalma1.java:74)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Sending signal. PID: 368 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Make sure this line  Intent i =new Intent(Kalma1.this, null);

Comment: write like this  Intent i =new Intent(Kalma1.this, YourNextActivity.java); instead of  Intent i =new Intent(Kalma1.this, null);

Comment: yes i don't want to call another activity. just want to exit from the application

Comment: then use only finish();

Comment: plz post more code or declaration of ----> kalma1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to finish only that activity then dont use any intent just write `finish()`

```
home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @baig772 Hmm just remember this & enjoy Android

Comment: sure, next time i will definitely remember this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i =new Intent(Kalma1.this, null);
```

is the prime cause of this `NullPointerException`.

You have to mention the name of the activity to which you want to navigate as second parameter.

### EDIT

Android's design does not favor exiting an application by choice, but rather manages it by the OS. You can bring up the Home application by its corresponding Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
Intent i =new Intent(Kalma1.this, null);
```

Refer [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/android-exit-application-code)

Comment: I don't want to call any other activity. Just want to exit from the current activity that's why used null

Comment: okay. Then you have to just call built-in method : `finish()`

Answer (score 0):

You should call it as below to finish your current activity:

```
home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            kalma1.stop();
            //Intent i =new Intent(Kalma1.this, null);
            //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            finish();
        }
    });
```