# How to exit a application in android

Tags: android

I am trying to apply exit functionality in my application on Home activity .I have tried some ways to perform my target like `System.Exit(0);` or `finish();` or `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());super.onDestroy();` but problem is if i navigate to another activity from home than i came back to home activity and  exit application it returns to previously navigated activity

Comment: Please upload your code.

Comment: Here is discussion of [Android- exit application code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/android-exit-application-code/15643706#15643706)
Hope this helps you..

Comment: There are tons of questions/answers about exiting. What do you want to do (exactly) and why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call finish() like below. So it will clear instance of the activity.

When you come back to HomeActivity from ActivityB try to call finish()

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, Home.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Pressing the Back button**strong text** does not "kill the app". **It finishes the activity that was on-screen when the user pressed the BACK button.**

Answer (score 0):

You should use broadcastreceiver to do this. When the user taps on the exit button for example, you should send an intent like

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(ACTION_LOGOUT);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And in the baseActivity you use (or in every activity of the project) use something like

```
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (ACTION_LOGOUT.equals(action)) {
        finish();
    }
}
};
```

and in the onCreate:

```
registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_LOGOUT));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to exit from your app :)

```
 finish();
    moveTaskToBack(true);
 System.exit(0);
```

Comment: System.exit() should only be used in specific cases.  Please do not recommend it.  Read the links to the discussions in the comments.

Comment: i have suggested system.exit(0) so that he will get back to home screen of app after destroying  it....other he will nevigate to the activity where he was at the time of exiting the app

Comment: There are documented, and recommended, Activity flags which should be used to control navigation.  System.exit() is just wrong.