# Android Application exit code for api level 21 and above?

Tags: android

I create a Expense Manager app.
I was write below code for exit But it work for `below api 21`
need help for exit code `API level 21`

```
public class Logout extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        {
          ***//Code for API level 21 and Above***
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
        }
}
public static void exitApplication(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Logout.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

    context.startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the below code to exit out of the application

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: [_Don't do this._](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480867/system-exit0-doesnt-close-all-my-activities)