# exit button in android not working

Tags: android, exit, activity-finish

I was trying to close app on click of button click.so i use the following code on home page

```
closebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
```

from `page5` clicking of `close button` Home page opens.

```
b5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i =new Intent(Page5.this, FirstPage.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

so when i click on close button in home page it is again going to page5 instead of closing app.

Please help me to find the problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16480930/2345913)

Comment: or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/android-exit-application-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`finish()` doesn't close the app. It only closes the current activity. So after finishing an activity the natural behavior is going back to the last activity of activity stack.

So now you have multiple options

1. finish the previous activity before starting next one
2. startactivityforresult to start second activity. When finished you can catch in onActivityResult to finish.

There are also other possible options.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 b5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i =new Intent(Page5.this, FirstPage.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Page5.this.finish();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You Add following code for **exit** the app.

```
closebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
           startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
           startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           startActivity(startMain);
       }
});
```

By using this code when you click on close button you directly redirect to device home screen.

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear the top activity. 
May be you can try something like this

Suppose in our application, we have a number of activities(say ten) and we need to exit directly from this activity. What we can do is, create an intent and go to the root activity and set flag in the intent as

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

also, add some extra like boolean to the intent

```
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
```

Then in root activity, check the value of the boolean and according to that call finish(), in the onCreate() of the root activity

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
 finish();
}
```