# how to finish application in android

Tags: android

How do i finish application? I use below code but is only finish current activity, go back to previous activity. I want to finish activity when button click i try `finish();` `system.exit(0);` but not helping me

```
    buttonwithleft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            quit(); 
        }
    });
    public void quit() {
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);

    System.exit(0);
   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17292441/931982

Comment: you should not doing this at all ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application-and-launch-home-screen-on-android/2043302#2043302 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Answer (score 1):

Try this code... I hope it is useful for you.

```
buttonwithleft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        quit(); 
    }
});
public void quit() {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```

that code working for me... and I think also working for you...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to finish all activities of your application you should maintain this flow.

Assume i am in Activity D. My actual flow is A->B->C->D.i want to kill my previous activities A,B,C. I used to call my first activity A when i am going from Activity D. So i added intent FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to call activity A. So the middle activities will cleared and will show only Activity A. And i am passing some flag value as intent extras to activity A. like this

```
         Intent intent = new Intent(D.this,A.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("finishstatus", true);
                this.startActivity(intent);
                this.finish();
```

and i am checking the bundle value in onCreate method of Activity A like

```
       bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!= null)
        {
       boolean isActivityToBeFinish =  this.getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("finishstatus");
            if(isActivityToBeFinish)
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
```

If the status value available and it is true the i am finishing the activity A also. So my problem is cleared and i am successfully finishing the all previous activities.

May be my explanation is not good but the final work is this only.

Comment: but im already finsish first activity when going to A->B->c

Comment: No you should not finish first activity A.You should close when you want to exit from the application. Then only this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:noHistory="true"` in your manifest file on each activity, then when you click on your button call the `finish();` function. This will exit your application. eg

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="name_of_act"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="act_name"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```