# How to exit an Android app programmatically?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I am sure this question has been asked number of times because I read a few. My client wants me to put a button into his app where users can click and exit. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238) and found calling `finish()` will do it. But, finish is only closing the current running activity right? I have lot of activities so in this case I have to pass each and every activity's instance and finish them or make every activity into Singleton pattern.

I also got to know `Activity.moveTaskToBack(true)` can get you into the home screen. OK, this is not closing but backgrounding the process. So is this is effective?

Which method should I use to close the app completely? Any of above described or any other method/other usage of above methods?

Comment: why not use action bar. click on app icon navigate to home screen. click backbutton to exit

Comment: @Raghunandan: As I mentioned, client requirement :(

Comment: Check if this helps android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: [Android exit application code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/android-exit-application-code) have a look at this post it may be useful for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/android-exit-application-code

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html. check this . only a suggestion. and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon

Comment: Couldn't you grab all running activities using the package manager, then call finish on all activities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit from the application and show the home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/how-to-exit-from-the-application-and-show-the-home-screen)

Answer (score 98):

The finishAffinity method, released in API 16, closes all ongoing activities and closes the app:

```
this.finishAffinity();
```

> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity. This is typically used when an application can be launched on to another task (such as from an ACTION_VIEW of a content type it understands) and the user has used the up navigation to switch out of the current task and in to its own task. In this case, if the user has navigated down into any other activities of the second application, all of those should be removed from the original task as part of the task switch.

> Note that this finish does not allow you to deliver results to the previous activity, and an exception will be thrown if you are trying to do so.

Since API 21, you can use:

```
finishAndRemoveTask();
```

> Finishes all activities in this task and removes it from the recent tasks list.

Alternatives:

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

```
Process.sendSignal(Process.myPid(), Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
```

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
i.putExtra(EXTRA_EXIT, true);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Source: [How to quit android application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically)

Comment: Don't use System.exit(). Android will attempt to restart the app after it exits. You could end up in a loop.

Comment: `System.exit(0)/exitProcess(0)` is the only one that truly worked for me (removed the process and triggered `File.deleteOnExit()`). Of course how useful that is on Android is another question.

Answer (score 78):

Actually everyone is looking for closing the application via an onclick event, wherever may be activity...

Add this code to an onclick event:

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
    homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
    startActivity(homeIntent);
```

Comment: This actually does not "close the app completely" like PeakGen asked since the app is still running but it's a nice alternative

Comment: I don't think so，if an activity started with FLAG ACTIVITY NEW TASK，this way can not exit it

Answer (score 49):

You can call System.exit(); to get out of all the acivities.

```
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

            submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                    System.exit(1);

                }
            });
```

Comment: It is just taking me to the first activity

Comment: @AnchitMittal System.exit(1) will not guarantee resetting the Activity stack or tasks (see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).  This approach, therefore, does not guarantee proper shutdown of the app (destroying all Activities) in due time.

Comment: Not all activity to exit.

Comment: System.exit() only works if you have a mono-activity app, so it's very very limited

Answer (score 48):

If you want to exit from your application, use this code inside your button pressed event:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  moveTaskToBack(true);
  android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 26):

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit Application?");
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                moveTaskToBack(true);
                                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                System.exit(1);
                            }
                        })

                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: What is different betweenn System.exit(1); and System.exit(0);

Comment: System.exit(1) means that the app finished with some error, while System.exit(0) means that the app finished without any error.
This is how various linux/unix commands return (error) conditions upon exit.

Answer (score 16):

It's way too easy. Use `System.exit(0);`

Comment: Hahahah. Not really too easy

Comment: Not really too easy but it must be. This is not a hard topic. We just only want to close the app. That's it :(

Answer (score 15):

Accually there are two possible situations:

1. You may want to exit from the activity
2. Or you want to exit from the application

You can exit from the activity using following code:

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryHome);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

But this will not kill the underlying activities in the same application.
This will just minimize the application.

If you want to exit from application use the following code to end its process:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

for mono development just use

```
process.KillProcess(Process.MyPid());
```

Comment: Mypid() is your method or what...... so how u have write Mypid ...u have to write with method.....

Comment: @amitsharma MyPid() is a method from Process class,  which Returns the identifier of this process, which can be used with killProcess(int) and sendSignal(int, int)

Comment: Would it stop the background service and broadcast receivers as well or just will safely close the app?

Comment: so, what's the difference between `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); ` and `process.KillProcess(Process.MyPid());`?

Answer (score 9):

How about `this.finishAffinity()`

From the docs,

> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity. This is typically used when an application can be launched on to another task (such as from an ACTION_VIEW of a content type it understands) and the user has used the up navigation to switch out of the current task and in to its own task. In this case, if the user has navigated down into any other activities of the second application, all of those should be removed from the original task as part of the task switch.
>   Note that this finish does not allow you to deliver results to the previous activity, and an exception will be thrown if you are trying to do so.

Answer (score 7):

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: For my case, this saved my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

this will clear Task(stack of activities)  and begin new Task

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
System.exit(1);
```

Comment: Explain why you posted this code as an answer and what it does too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(homeIntent);
System.exit(1);
```

Use this Code it's much useful, and you can exit all of the activities.

Answer (score 3):

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
        homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Achieving in Xamarin.Android:

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        MoveTaskToBack(true);
        Process.KillProcess(Process.MyPid());
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Is this a reference to System.Environment.Exit or Android.OS.Environment.Exit?

Answer (score 2):

put this one into your onClic:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
    finish()
```

Comment: whats wrong with the downvoted. This is the answer. I got 2 activities, 1st is loginactivity and 2nd is mainactivity.... i wanted to exit app within mainactivity and dont want to go back to loginactivity...i insert this answer, and now I can close the app within mainactivity.

Comment: if you do this the application will still be running the background

Comment: Working fine. My case is: splashActivity run MainActivity. When user press back on MainActivity application exits as expected. All other cases are got me back to the splash activity !

Comment: Well, you should've finished the login activity as soon as login's finished:) And the answer is of course **not completely correct**, `movewTaskToBack` finishes nothing it just **hide** the app, and `finish` as mentioned by anyone else finishes only the current `activity`. So it quits current activity and hides the rest, if any presents. Anyway it should not get a down vote just for this...

Answer (score 2):

Try this on a call. I sometimes use it in onClick of a button.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

It instead of closing your app , opens the dashboard so kind of looks like your app is closed.

read this question for more clearity
[android - exit application code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/android-exit-application-code/3226743#3226743)

Answer (score 2):

Use this.finishAffinity(); on that button instead of finish(); 
If it does not work then you can also try by adding android:noHistory="true" in your manifest and then finish your activity by uisng finish(); or finishAffinity();

Hope it helps....:)

Answer (score 2):

Just call these two functions

```
 finish();
 moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Comment: Your answer came in lower quality posts. Please provide some explanation even though your code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Link this method to your quit/exit button

```
public void quitGame(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            finishAndRemoveTask();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

ghost activity called with singletop and finish() on onCreate should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

It works using only `moveTaskToBack(true);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of System.exit(1) Just use System.exit(0)

Answer (score 1):

```
finish();
 finishAffinity();
 System.exit(0);
```

worked for me

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Additionally, it looks like other answers already covered that - so you should also explain what makes your solution better than the others

Answer (score 1):

If someone still wonders, for **Xamarin.Android** (in my case also Monogame running on it) the command `FinishAndRemoveTask()` on `Activity` does the job very well!

Answer (score 1):

in the fragment

getActivity().finishAndRemoveTask();

in the Activity

finishAndRemoveTask();

Answer (score 0):

just use the code in your backpress

```
                    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(startMain);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) (or really any other pub/sub library) in your application to communicate between activities you can send them an explicit event:

```
final public class KillItWithFireEvent
{
    public KillItWithFireEvent() {}

    public static void send()
    {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new KillItWithFireEvent());
    }
}
```

The only downside of this is you need all activities to listen to this event to call their own `finish()`. For this you can easily create *shim* activity classes through inheritance which just listen to this event and let subclasses implement everything else, then make sure all your activities inherit from this extra layer. The kill listeners could even add some extra functionality through overrides, like avoiding death on certain particular situations.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the below two lines when you want to exit from the application

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call this:

```
finishAffinity();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This can work I tried it too.

`this.finishAffinity();`

Answer (score 0):

**In Fragment use** `getActivity().finishAffinity();` and clear `fragment` binding without memory leaks

Answer (score -1):

If you use both finish and exit your app will close complitely

finish();

System.exit(0);