# Alert Dialog - how to?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Can someone tell me how exit all activity on android studio, because when show alert dialog exit i click exit when progressbar on proses the app close but few second app auto start and show second activity.

Comment: Is this Android or AndroidStudio question? As far as I can tell, Android studio doesn't have "activities".

Comment: Build app using android studio and running on android,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to exit app when user pressing yes on alert box.. so for this you need to write below code on "yes" button click like this.
Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24057506/6764161)

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit Application?");
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            moveTaskToBack(true);
                            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                            System.exit(1);
                        }
                    })

            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude that working

Comment: Good for you, but these kind of code is easy to find on internet or even on stackoverflow, just search a little bit before asking a question. :)

Comment: Ok i will try it ,, :D