# What is the best way to finish() an activity from a foreground service without bringing the app to the foreground?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-pendingintent

I am trying to build an app that can be used for calling.
My `CallActivity` is declared `singleTop` in the manifest file. I have a foreground service (`CallService`) which is started as soon as the app goes to the background while the user is on a call, since the device must not sleep during a call.

The notification for my `CallService` allows the user to either resume the call or hangup. My goal is to have the user press a button on the notification and hangup the ongoing call without bringing the app to the foreground.

I have tried using `PendingIntent.getActivity()` to start the CallActivity once the app is in background, from the CallService. But I have not been able to hangup the call yet. Here is some code...

```
 Intent returnToCallIntent = new Intent(this, CallActivity.class);
 PendingIntent returnPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, returnToCallIntent, 0);

 Intent hangUpCallIntent = new Intent(this, CallActivity.class);
 hangUpCallIntent.putExtra("ACTION_FINISH_ACTIVITY", true);
 PendingIntent hangUpPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, hangUpCallIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Right now both pending intents resolve to the same action which is hanging up the call while bring the app to the foreground. I figured out that this is happening because the 2 intents only differ in their extras and hence android does not distinguish them, i.e. `intent#filterEquals()` does not see any difference between them.

But the more important question is how can I `finish()` the `CallActivity` and have it pop off the backstack silently, without bringing it to the foreground. Also, after the `CallActivity` has been stopped, I need to stop the `CallService` in the background. So when the user taps the app in the recents screen, she/he should see the activity which was prior to the `CallActivity` on the backstack.

PS: Logic to hang up the call has been done in `onNewIntent()` method in `CallActivity`.

Comment: `System.exit(1);` See [How to exit an Android app programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719634/how-to-exit-an-android-app-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks @JonGoodwin but `System.exit()` seems to be a bit harsh. I tried the solution suggested by @David Wasser below and it seems to work well.

Comment: `System.exit()` is definitely not what you want. Android interprets that as "your app crashed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your `Activity` register an anonymous `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for a specific broadcast `Intent`. When your `Service` wants to finish the `Activity`, it can just send the broadcast `Intent` that the `Activity` is listening for.

In `onReceive()` of the `BroadcastReceiver`, just call `finish()`. This won't bring the `Activity` to the foreground.

Comment: Thank you @David Wasser. The solution works really well. Unfortunately my upvote will not reflect until I get more reputation :(

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. That will help others with a similar problem. It will also get the question off the list of unanswered questions, as well as giving me some reputation points.