# How to exit the app when bottomsheetdialog showing

Tags: java, android, kotlin, onbackpressed, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have bottomsheet that check if the internet connected or not! if no connected the bottomsheet showed, if not the bottomsheet dismiss. I used `bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();` function to prevent the user from pressing the screen to hide the bottomsheet. Now what I want is that the user **if press back when bottomsheet showed exit the app**.

> not exit bottocheet first and then exit the app

Here's what I made so far

I used an interface called **IOnBackPressed**, And I Override exit app from "MainActivty" with this code

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_layout);
    if (!(fragment instanceof IOnBackPressed)) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

And I added the exit app method in the fragment that has the bottomsheet "HomeFragment"

```
 @Override
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
    requireActivity().moveTaskToBack(true); //exit the app when press back
    requireActivity().finish();
    return true;
}
```

**But it is not working, and when I press back it does not exit the app.**

Here is my method for bottomsheetdialog

```
    private void showBottomSheetDialog() {
    bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(requireContext());
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheet_no_internet);
    if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(requireActivity())) {
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
    } else {
        bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false);
        bottomSheetDialog.show();
    }
    Button buttonNoInternet = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonNoInternet);
    assert buttonNoInternet != null;
    buttonNoInternet.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(requireActivity())) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            bottomSheetDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

So how can I do that?

Comment: "when I press back it does not exit the app" ->what happens when you press back button?does it call bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()? @Moataz

Comment: `public boolean onBackPressed(){ ...  return super.onBackPressed();}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default when the back key pressed  while a `BottomSheetDialog` is showing, the activity's `onBackPressed()` won't be called.. You probably can try to put a break point inside `onBackPressed()` and see.

So, a workaround other than `onBackPressed()` is to attach a Key listener to the `BottomSheetDialog` and check the code of the pressed key that matches the back code; and there you can dismiss the dialog and exit the app:

```
bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(requireContext()) {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    // Back key is pressed

                    bottomSheetDialog.dismiss(); // Optional
                    requireActivity().moveTaskToBack(true); //exit the app when press back
                    requireActivity().finish();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button buttonNoInternet = findViewById(R.id.buttonNoInternet);
        buttonNoInternet.requestFocus();

    }

};
```

**UPDATE:**

> When I try this code I MUST click on tryAgain Button and then I can exit the app. But it is not exit the app when BottomSheet showen

So, The reason that the dialog is shown earlier than the `BottomSheetFragment` is shown on the screen, so, you need to show it when the the `BottomSheetFragment` is shown on the screen:

So this part of code need to be transferred to `BottomSheetFragment` `onResume()` method:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(requireActivity())) {
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
    } else {
        bottomSheetDialog.show();
    }
}
```

And you can just setup the `DialogFragment` like said in `onCreate()` method of the `BottomSheetFragment`

Comment: When I try this code I MUST click on tryAgain Button and then I  can exit the app. But it is not exit the app when BottomSheet showen

Comment: @Moataz Can you show this part of the code.. I can't see the `tryAgain` button in the question

Comment: Check out the codes In My Fraggment. https://github.com/MoatazBadawy/MOX/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/moataz/mox/ui/view/fragment/HomeFragment.java

Comment: @Moataz Can you try this: `@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Button buttonNoInternet = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonNoInternet);
        buttonNoInternet.requestFocus();
    }`

Comment: Great, I use it but getting this error "get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail."

Comment: And without add "assert buttonNoInternet != null;", getting this error "boolean android.widget.Button.requestFocus()' on a null object reference"

Comment: You are right because this is part of the fragment.. I meant to use it in the bottomSheetDialog .. Please check updated answer

Comment: @Moataz Any good news or we can think of something else

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but also not working. could we chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234443/discussion-between-zain-and-moataz).

Answer (score 2):

Below code will work as expected, I'll share you my code snippet.

Inside MainActivity I have below code for exit the app

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Inside fragment I have a bottomsheet dialog. Please note my MainActivity consist of fragment

Code for bottomsheet dialog

```
private void openDialogCategoryList() {

        BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mActivity, R.style.DialogStyle);
        BottomSheetDialogLayoutCountryCodeBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mActivity),
                R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_layout_country_code, null, false);
        dialog.setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet).setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);


        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                                 KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                countProductType = 0;
            }
        });

        binding.txtTitle.setText("Select Product Type");
        binding.edtSearch.setHint("Search Product Type");

      
        binding.txtClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        binding.flOpenClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Feel free to ask if you have doubt

Comment: can you please share your code so i can help you as it worked for me soo...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your back stack state. Is it the last Activity on that stack that is showing the Bottom Sheet Dialog? If it is then you can use a callback function that will call `finish()` on that activity. If it not, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21576676/8413748) reference that states

1. You can exit from the activity using the following code (But this will not kill the underlying activities in the same application. This will just minimize the application)

   ```
   var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
   intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryHome);
   intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();
   ```
2. Killing the process

   ```
   android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
   ```

Comment: I use Java not kotlin

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because the `BottomSheetDialog` is a `Dialog` which has it's own `onBackPressed()`.
You need to override the following in your `BottomSheetDialog`:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new Dialog(getActivity(), getTheme()){
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // Maybe check before if there still no connection
            requireActivity().moveTaskToBack(true);
            requireActivity().finish();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

or

```
System.exit(0);
```

or

```
finishAffinity();
finish();
```

Comment: In onBackPressed that inside TopFragment?