# How to exit from an application after click default back in android?

Tags: android, exit, back

I want to exit from application after click back in android phone.Actually i do not know the exact word for that back option.[Screen shot of back option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMJpk.png)

I really know the way to exit from application after click button.So how can i code for that?can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity you can override method onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  finish();
}
```

If you have stack of activities
there are better way:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  moveTaskToBack(true);
  android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I had stack of activities so i used 2nd one.That worked for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the logic and attached it to a button, you can override

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

in your activity, and put the same logic in there

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/how-to-exit-from-the-application-and-show-the-home-screen) question:

> Android's design does not favor exiting an application by choice, but
>   rather manages it by the OS. You can bring up the Home application by
>   its corresponding Intent:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(intent);
```

Note that his will not kill your app process, but rather put your activity on the background.
As for when to trigger this code, you should override the `onBackPressed()` method for your current activity.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by this code (if you only have just one activity remining in your current backstack.) corrected by  feresr

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// your code, what to do under back arrow button.
    finish();  // to finish app or activity

}
```

Comment: This will work if OP only have just one activity remining in your current backstack. Could be the case