# finish() not working as expected

Tags: java, android, activity-finish

As I'm creating an android application in which first I've created main activity, then I've added splash activity along with the one normal activity.

So my **problem** is whenever I **click on exit** in my app it **closes** the main activity and **returns** that **one normal activity in splash activity.**
I am using **`finish();`** on exit button which is present in main activity.

So how can I exit the app which **comes** to android launcher screen

I've also tried creating **new intent** with **Action Main** but its only **minimizing the app** I want to close it

**MainActivity.class**

```
if (id == R.id.exit) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(homeActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Do You Want To Exit?").setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_black_24dp);
            alert.setTitle("Exit!!");
            alert.show();
      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit from the application and show the home screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/how-to-exit-from-the-application-and-show-the-home-screen)

Comment: dismiss your splash activity when you start main activity from it.

Comment: it is happening because first activity is still in the stack

Comment: This issue is not with Your MainActivity. While pushing your MainActivity, need to finish the SplashScreen and use tags as specified by @Trucket

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When starting the `MainAcitivity` from `SplashActivity` set flags in intent as below and call `finish()` on `SplashAcitivty`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 3):

you can set `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` and `android:noHistory="true"`
in you android `Manifest` file for the splash activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding flag `"Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP"` while you launch `MainActivity` from your `SplashScreenActivity`, as below:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: i have tried but its not working in following way i have added `Intent inst = new Intent(ipInfo.this,homeActivity.class);
                                    inst.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(inst);`

Comment: after starting the activity  i have set `finish();` then it works as i expected thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

add this things in splash while navigating splash to mainActivity

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
finish();
```