# Android press home screen buttom and close application

Tags: android

When I pressed the home button, it will return to home, but the app is still running in the background.

How can I make my app completely shut down after pressing the home button?

Comment: Can I know why you want this?

Comment: You can use onPause() method and onDestroy() method to finish activity.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279292/how-to-close-an-application-when-the-home-button-is-pressed?rq=1

Comment: use onclick method and close the activity using getActivity().finish();

Comment: @Pan Long  I'm using webview but when I press the home button to leave rather than back button,next time I open this app the screen will stop at a white screen not open the website.So I guess I need to finish the activity when press home button.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Add these lines inside the Aandroid Manifest in activity that you launches...

Comment: Can you explain why you add this three line

Answer (score 1):

Check out the solution of this question and override accordingly.

[Can I override the 'Home' button in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547818/can-i-override-the-home-button-in-my-application)

Comment: @YichenWang the solution here might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208912/how-can-i-detect-user-pressing-home-key-in-my-activity