# KILL APPLICATION ONPAUSE

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've very little knowledge about all this codes, but I'm building an application, and I want to kill the application onPause. Please give me a code by which I can kill the application.

Comment: I'M SORRY, I CAN'T HEAR WHAT YOU'RE SAYING. WHAT IS THIS TALK OF KILLING?! KILLING IS BAD! No, seriously - it is.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear even if it was originally written in capitals. The questioner wants to know how to code an Android application to exit when it receives a pause event.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, rich. I was not serious and I was trying to make a sarcastic response that also played a little on the concept that completely killing an Android application is bad form.

Comment: Hi Klaus. My comment was intended to justify my reopen vote. This looks like a real programming question that could have been (and was) reasonably answered in its original form. I have no problem with jokes in comments, non-native English speakers, or text entered without a standard keyboard.

Comment: to my knowledge ALL CAPS is used to express your anger on screen.. better avoid it user728859

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use all caps.

```
... onPause(){
    finish();
}
```

You shouldn't use System.exit(0); but since your question is in all caps you probably will.

Other ways to exit app and reason to not use System.exit:

[Close application and launch home screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/android-close-application)

Comment: one must call finish(), not onFinish().

Comment: thank you. and next time i'm surely not gonna use caps, but, wasn't aware of the fact that it can turn into something else...lol..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit the application then use System.exit in over ridden onPause method