# How to force close the app when using multiple activity

Tags: android

How to quit the app or force close the app when multiple activity running in background. I tried to give `system.exit(0)`, but this will works only having single activity. In my app i have 3 activity when i tried `system.exit` it kills that particular activity and go back to previous activity. please guide me to solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while starting Activity call `startActivityForResult();`
and in the same class override method `onActivityzResult()` and call `finish();` inside it.. do the same in all other activities..

Comment: Thanks, i cant understand where to put onActivityResult() and finish(). whether to put in same class (while calling activity) or inside the calling class..??

Comment: I have given this, but existing activity is not closed.. I gave startActivityForResult(); in calling class, and onActivityzResult() in both the class inside that i given finish. but nothing is happened..

Comment: then try to kill it using system.exit() in places where u ve put finish() or add "int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);" in place of finish() like selva said

Comment: can you give some example link to understand this issue. i tried so many times but nothing is happened. I hope i cant able to understand what you mentioned above.I am new to android can you pls guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Hello u can use your  System.exit(0);

if u call your next activity onClick
//

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YOURActivity.class);    

startActivity(i);  

System.exit(0);
```

It just force close your app and reopen called activity..

Not the right way but its working x)

Atleast for me when i had problem with multiple activity with gps location

Answer (score 0):

You can use startActivityForResult, and then when the activity on the stack finish, sends a integer back to the previous activity, there you can do the same until you finish the 1st activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kill or stop your app, you can try this,

```
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another dummy idea is u can create another dummy activity and just add finish method in it.. and in  your 3rd activity start this activity with intent as `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`..

Answer (score 0):

I also thought that. But I think shouldnt be right...Better to send the result to the previous activity. But Also I think closing the application from any activity is not the way Android is design. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/android-close-application)