# Finish, reload activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have application where Activity A allows to set some options and starts (after click on button) Activity B. User can do something in B and when he finishes, he has choice (RadioButtons):

1. repeat - it means the B Activity will run again with the same options (taken from A),
2. new  - it means application finishes B Activity and goes back to A, where user can set options again and start B again,
3. end - it goes out from application (I suppose it should finish B and then A Activity).

First I have done this way:

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
```

Another way I could use is to clean all parameters in this Activity, but above was more quickly.

Second is just a `finish()`.

Third is the biggest problem and i don't know how to to this. I tried with `startActivityForResult()`, `onActivityResult()` and `setResult()` but i saw it's impossible to set different results depending on selected RadioButton.

Other method I found is

```
public static void closeAllBelowActivities(Activity current) {
boolean flag = true;
Activity below = current.getParent();
if (below == null)
    return;
System.out.println("Below Parent: " + below.getClass());
while (flag) {
    Activity temp = below;
    try {
        below = temp.getParent();
        temp.finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        flag = false;
    }
}
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application)

But don't know how to put in current Activity.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to keep track of the `Intent` used to call B. Try the `putExtra()` method of the intent to B. You can also package everything into a `Bundle` and restore it with `getExtras()` (if I recall correctly, that's the method name). When on B, read the Intent used to call it and save the parameters. You also need to startActivityForResult(B) for the following to work.

> repeat - it means the B Activity will run again with the same options
>   (taken from A),

You probably want to call, from B, Activity B again using the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) flag in this case. I assume you don't want to have two B instances. Otherwise, just don't use the flag.

Put the `Bundle` you received from the Intent (from A) again, and catch it (if using single top) in the `onNewIntent()` method (or just normally, onCreate, if not single top). It goes like this: B -> B onPause() -> B onNewIntent() -> B onResume().

> new - it means application finishes B Activity and goes back to A,
>   where user can set options again and start B again,

Depending on the exact behavior you want, you could call A with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. In this case, you end up with A in the foreground and B in the background (pressing back will go back to B).

Or you could call finish() if you just don't want B anymore, and want to go back to A.

> end - it goes out from application (I suppose it should finish B and
>   then A Activity).

Do nothing on B, setResult() to something like "RESULT_FINISH_EVERYTHING", and when taking care of the results in A (override "onActivityResult()", IIRC), finish activity A also.

> but i saw it's impossible to set different results depending on
>   selected RadioButton.

You could setResult() depending on thw button checked in the radio button. You can set listeners to the radio group and read which button is selected. See `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` or `View.OnClickListener` if you need actions for eadch individual radio button.

Really, not too complicated. It just depends on what you want. I can clarify all this if you want.

Good luck!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I explained all the general design ceoncepts you needed in your app.

Answer (score 3):

"i saw it's impossible to set different results depending on selected RadioButton" isn't really clear to me. Anyway, I suggest you what I would do: Activity A starts Activity B with startActivityForResult() and A wait for a bundle coming from B. When you build the exit function from B to A, create a bundle with your result. In A, you will analyze the bundle coming from B and decide what to do with. If you would exit, call finish().

Edit: Ok this could be your case:

Activity A:

```
    public class XY extends Activity { 
    // you need that as a flag to go back and forth:
           protected static final int SUB_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_04 = 5337; // choose the number you want...
    int result_from_B; // I usually use an int, choose as you want....
    static final String KEY_FROM_B = "mKey";
    @Override 
      protected void onActivityResult(int result,int resultCode,Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(result, resultCode, data);
    if (result == SUB_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_04) {
            if (data!=null){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                result_from_B = extras.getInt(XY.KEY_FROM_B);
if (result_from_B==1) {
// do what you want
} else {
// do somthing else...
}
}
```

To call the Activity B, use this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, 
                    ActB.class);
            this.startActivityForResult(i,SUB_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_04);
```

In the Activity B:

```
public class ActB extends Activity{ 
    protected final int SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE = 1; // you need it to come back
int result; // this is the result to give to activity A
}
// in the function to build the output:
// I suppose you have already put something in result:
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(XY.KEY_FORM_B, result);
            Intent mIntent = new Intent();
            mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            ActB.this.setResult(SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE,mIntent);
            finish();
```

This is basic. You can manage also booleans back and forth, arrays, all you want (admitted by a bundle). Just put it in a bundle and go :)
Don't forget to declare your classes (activities) in the Manifest otherwise it will throw an exception runtime.

Comment: "i saw it's impossible to set different results depending on selected RadioButton" 
it means that I don't know how to switch that what setResult possess when one of the RadioButton is selected. But it was my wrong understanding. 

What I think I understand now:
I can't e.g setResult(1) when RadioButton1 is seleced, setResult(2) when RadioButton2 is seleced ... and then decide what to do in main activity depending on result value.

Comment: But saw I can in setRessult() put not only resultCode but also Intent data and make decisions with this. This is propably the hint what you **Zappescu** wanted to give me. So I can put data into bundle and then bundle into intent. 

Unfortunatelly still have problem, have "Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=77, result=0, data=null} to activity".
Do you know maybe some example?

Comment: Ah ok. So you can do it, just create a bundle with your result (in B) and when you come back to A, pick up the result from the bundle. Bundles act like a messenger with info between activities. You can use it back and forth, switching from one to the other activity, they are really useful.Edit: I just read your answer. Well, I have somthing write somewhere... give me the time to pick up.