# How to close our application in back button in android

Tags: android

I want to close my whole application when click on device's back button. How can I do this? Please help me.

thank you

Comment: Why do you want to close the whole application? That's something which doesn't belong to the android lifecycle. Please reconsider your design because it smells very wrong: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 2):

That's one of most useless desires of beginner Android developers, and unfortunately it seems to be very popular. How do you define "close" an Android application? Hide its user interface? Interrupt background work? Stop handling broadcasts?

Android applications are a set of modules, bundled in an .apk and exposed to the system through `AndroidManifest.xml`. Activities can be arranged and re-arranged through different task stacks, and finish()-ing or any other navigating away from a single Activity may mean totally different things in different situations. Single application can run inside multiple processes, so killing one process doesn't necessary mean there will be no application code left running. And finally, BroadcastReceivers can be called by the system any time, recreating the needed processes if they are not running.

The main thing is that you don't need to stop/kill/close/whatever your app trough a single line of code. Doing so is an indication you missed some important point in Android development. If for some bizarre reason you have to do it, you need to finish() all Activities, stop all Services and disable all BroadcastReceivers declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`. That's not a single line of code, and maybe launching the Activity that uninstalls your own application will do the job better.

Comment: finish() closes single activity only, not entire application. System.exit(0) is ok but not good.

Comment: @YugandharBabu no, calling System.exit is *not* ok. It does not go along with Android's activity lifecycle

Comment: Application opens, detects there is no login to the web service and launches a new activity asking for login credentials. User hits back. Application detects there is no credentials and immediately re-launches the activity asking for login credentials. So, perhaps the login credentials dialog needs a way to NOT let the app go back to the main screen to finish running. So there are use cases where it's needed.  One workaround is to use a shared preference that stores the fact you want to close the app, and check that in onResume on the main activity.

Answer (score 1):

I think its not possible to close entire application. see these links it may help you.

[Close Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application)

[How to exit an Android Application](http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_exit_an_Android_application.rhtml)

It may help you check it.

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
```

Answer (score 1):

call the moveTaskToBack() method inside the onKeyDown.

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        return true; //not sure this is needed
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: -1 finish() just closes the current activity but not the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

You can Call finish(); in back button

Comment: -1 finish() just closes the current activity but not the whole application.

Comment: Actually before it,a thread is working means a background Activity will call,when i do finish then activity will not finish it will reopen

Comment: hmm it will close the current activity.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you starts an activity just put

> finish();

before

> startActivity(intent);

This is the way to close your application with back button.

Comment: I can't understand what you exactly want??

Comment: The whole android framework is designed around a lifecycle (see link above). Misusing such methods (for example if you have a activity for sending a sms finishing it on the click of the send button is OK) for existing apps is against the design principile. This is very bad for UX. As mentioned in the first link of Yugandhar.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'm using this code:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on your activity When clicked android back button application closed but running in background! You can add **finish()** and **System.exit(0)**

> ```
> @Override
> public void onBackPressed() {
>     super.onBackPressed();
>     moveTaskToBack(true);
> }
> ```