# How to destroy an application with all its activities using exit button

Tags: java, android

I want to destroy whole application when am clicking exit button....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code to close your application and all its activities

```
finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
        startActivity(intent);
```

[Close application and launch home screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application)

Comment: its working but when i open application again it shows the previous activity how to exit...

Comment: check in your task manager that after exiting application is there alive or not ??

Comment: okay i want to say when you call this segment all activities shoul get closed if they are not getting close there may be some problem but this way is very good to close application rather then system.exit(0);

Comment: if you have any problem let me know

Answer (score 0):

There is no **Exit** button concept in *Android*. Simply call `finish();` on your activities to destroy them.

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking, as this will not destroy a parent activity when called from a child.

Comment: Not quite.  The concept is there: it means finish **all** activities of the application.  I've seen quite a few apps that include *exit* function.  Check Opera Mobile, for example.

Comment: that exit button is to kill any service in case they are running and/or to give user a feel that the app is closed (as in windows), otherwise it can always be resumed from Activity Stack. And if there was an exit concept by android, then they must have had provided something like *context.exit();* but unfortunately they dont

Answer (score 0):

The most straight way is

```
finish();
System.exit(0);
```