# How to exit the application completely from any screen

Tags: android, exit, activity-finish

I want to exit the android application completely from any screen i also tried `System.exit(0);` and `finish();` but it only exit the current activity i want to exit completely. I used menu option for exit can any one help me in coding.

Comment: check [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4c1b8955ebfd5799)

Comment: There are many similar questions like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238) also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used this in your coding in your program

`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

this will kill your process

Answer (score 2):

Press the **home button**! you're done!

You need not really think about exiting the application(assuming you're asking for a exit button). This is not how Android apps usually work.

Please read upon this link for more information : [When to Include an Exit Button in Android Apps (Hint: Never)](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html)

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033914/977676) question also might be helpful.

Comment: when i used home button the activity and services run in bg when i click the app again it comes to a same activity  i want to restart the app when i exit and come back

Comment: @user179777 if you want to go that way, use `android:noHistory="true"` in the manifest for all your activities :) and `finish()` your current activity ..youre done! :)

Comment: and also i want the back button in android to be work if i put this the back button will be working ?

Comment: @user179777 umm I dont get you completeley.the back key will work fine and if want to do something when user presses the back key, you should  be overriding `onBackPressed ()` method ..

Comment: i try the android:noHistory="true" is working fine but i can't used he back button in android the project exit when i click the back button any solution

Comment: @user179777 what you want when you press back?

Answer (score 0):

**ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(PackageName)** will be helpful.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score -1):

When you start an activity, use startActivityForResult().

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, ActivitiesRequests.REQUEST_FROM_NEW_ACTIVITY);
```

Then, if an activity wants to signal its caller to exit as well, it can use a result code: setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);. It is then caught in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
    case ActivitiesRequests.REQUEST_FROM_NEW_ACTIVITY:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            finish();
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: can u give some example for this plz