# How to close an Android Application which contain many activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have an application with 6 activities,

```
* Home--> A1 ---> A5
* Home--> A2 ---> A5
* Home--> A3 ---> A5
* Home--> A4 ---> A5
```

And with a menu which can reach directly Home, A1, A2, A3 and A4 from any activities.

I want to add to the menu an item "Exit application".

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no real "Exit" concept in Android - and your design should not allow users to do so. Take a look at this and see if you can use this thread
[Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that.
Android is designed to manage processes on its own.
It will close your application when free memory level becomes low.

User can simply go out of your application by pressing home button.

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish()` in every `Activity` when you move from one `Activity` to another(before the `startActivity()` call). That way, there will be no `Activity` running. And then, whenever you want to exit, simply call `finish()` on the current `Activity` too.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for yours precious answers, i resolve it my self, i think the right way to impose a navigation model is to add global variables of control like:

```
boolean comeFromA;
boolean comeFromHome;
```

and case those variables you do the necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and even though it is apparenetly against the whole idea, I just wanted to nuke the app, as it was causing problems of various sorts that I could not figure it out without breaking another part and it did not matter if it started from scratch everytime. (And I did not want to spend any more days hurting my head with it.)

After trying all of the answers from this question and many similar ones I worked out that doing this in each activity solved it.

```
@Override protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    super.finish();
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
}
```

(For now at least, as I believed I solved it a few times before).

Answer (score -1):

For "Exit application" you can use -

```
System.exit();
```

Comment: It is not advisable to use it.

Comment: Doing this is against Android's development paradigm, if you wish to suggest it, you should provide a _very_ good reason for doing so.