# Removing an activity from the stack

Tags: android, android-activity

When going from activity A to B, I want to clear A off the stack: so when the user is pressing the back button in activity B, the app exits.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

These code lines do not work - the app goes back to activity A. I've also tried to OR with the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, same result. I've actually also tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`.

I'm using Android 2.2 for my app.

Comment: it works!!! if app exits and if you have two activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call finish() after you call startActivity(). It should clear Activity A from the stack. In code it looks like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions: in your B activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed(); //not sure if this line is needed
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Or a much nicer: Start your activity with startActivityForResult, and implement your A activity's onActivityResult method:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
   finish();
}
```

Comment: `System.exit(0)` is highly disregarded in Android development.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation please?

Comment: `finish()` is always the way to go, never `System.exit()`. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application) for a good discussion on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

[`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)

> If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished. This may also be set with the `noHistory` attribute.

So, You can implement this from your

AndroidManifest.xml file,

**`android:noHistory="true"`**