# Close android application programmatically

Tags: android

How can i close my application programmatically?

I used

```
   finish();
```

Or

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Or

```
System.exit(0);
```

Or

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

but it closed the current running activity, but i need to close the whole application??

I need to close app to retrieve some memory and then restart application again.

Or

does there is a way to clear all memory of the application?

Comment: You should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application

Comment: Try to figure out whatever is leaking memory and fix that. I assume it might have something to do with bitmaps.

Comment: I recycled all bitmaps and also received OOM

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using these lines in your activity:-

```
this.finish();
Process.killProcess( Process.myPid() );
```

will kill your whole application (assuming its running in a single process) it will also free any associated memory.

WARNING: On some phones doing this may leave bluetooth sockets dangling if you are using them.

Comment: This didn't help me. actually situation is like- I have to activity A and B and when user is on activity B and pressed back then it will be redirected to Activity A by using intent. and I want when user is on activity A now and pressed back key, whole application should be closed as Activity A is Main Activity. But What is happening is that- when user is on activity A and pressed back then activity B comes on front. Please give any advice how can i close by application if user is on main activity and pressed back button.

Comment: @neel you should not start another instance of A from B. In A use `startActivityForResult()` and exit B using `this.setResult()` with `this.finish()`. Activity A now received a parameter from B, without starting another instance.

Comment: @David: what about 'System.exit(0);' ,does this also leave the bluetooth sockets dangling if we use them? .If yes,what other methods are there to gracefully close an application?

Comment: By the way, this is totally bad practice! Do not kill process!