# Close a background android application

Tags: android

The requirement is to kill an application which is pushed to the background after a time interval. How can i do that in android? If anybody could share the code snippet, it would be great.

Thanks,
Jinu

Comment: Shouldn't this be handled at the Operating System level?

Comment: The Android OS is perfectly capable of killing an App in the background. Don't interfere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386394/close-android-application-programmatically

Comment: I assume you would want to kill applications other than yours ?

Answer (score 0):

The android framework does not provide permission to kill other app process.
You can only kill your app processes.

Process kill permission is only for system apps.

Still try using this permission in your Menifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
```