# onBackPressed button My application not properly close?

Tags: android

onBackPressed button my application not properly close. Its again registered my application in background. Its not properly close from background.please tell me how can I close properly

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit from application ?");

    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



prefProviderWrapper.setPreferenceBooleanValue(PreferencesWrapper.HAS_BEEN_QUIT, true);
    moveTaskToBack (false);
Context context= getApplicationContext();
Communicator comm= new Communicator(context);
Activity app=getParent();
comm.CloseApplication(app);
    finish(); 


}
});
```

Comment: what actually happen when you press back button.?

Comment: its again registered and show message in notification

Comment: registered means what happend actually?

Comment: sir its start again and show message in notification area

Answer (score 1):

set `launchmode ="singleTask"` in manifest file for your activity and invoke `YourActvity.this.finish()` and `System.exit(0)`  inside `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: can we give single task mode to fragments..?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is not advised doing that in an Android application as Romain Guy says: "You should really think about not exiting the application. This is not how Android apps usually work."

But if you still want to achieve this, refer to these topics on stackoverflow which already have very detailed answers and guides for properly closing/quitting/killing your application:

[How to close Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application)

[Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon?lq=1)

[Close application and launch home screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application-and-launch-home-screen-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use this on back button press

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(setIntent);
    return;
}
```

Comment: can you say difference between FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and setting the launch mode of an activity to singleTask..?

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK produces the same behavior as the "singleTask" launchMode, If there's already an existing task with the same affinity as the new activity, the activity is launched into that task. If not, it begins a new task.