# WL.App.overrideBackButton doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Mobilefirst Platform 7.1. I am trying override standard behavior of back button in Android. I created new Mobilefirst project "Hello Mobilefirst". In **main.js** I am overriding back button functionality. I ran the App on Samsung Note 4 and back button only closing the App not showing a message. If I am using **alert** instead of **WL.SimpleDialog.show** the App is showing message, but after that it is closing the App. How can I close the app only when I am pressing YES?

**index.html**

```
<body style="display: none;">
        Hello MobileFirst
        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
function wlCommonInit(){

}

WL.App.overrideBackButton(checkQuit());

function checkQuit() {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show(
            "Quit application", 
            "Are you sure?", 
            [
             {text: "Yes", handler: function() {WL.App.close();}},
             {text: "No", handler: function() {}}
             ]
    );
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to find the client environment and write the following code in main.js file.

```
if(WL.Client.getEnvironment().toUpperCase() == "ANDROID"){
      WL.App.overrideBackButton(backFunc); 
       }
function backFunc() {
           // alert('You will back to previous page');
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The WL.App.close() API will no longer actually quit the app because that is not the recommended behavior. Not by Apple nor by Google.  If you want to force-quit the app you will need to trigger native code that will do this instead.

See here: [What is the substitute for WL.App.close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793058/what-is-the-substitute-for-wl-app-close)

Comment: Actually, i don't need close the App. I need keep it running, but back button is closing it. Instead of WL.App.close() could be a different function.